# Regex to compare two strings with slashes

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have the following string

```
"qu'ils/elles essayent/essaient"
```

The following strings should all match

```
"qu'ils essayent"

"qu'ils/elles essayent/essaient"

"qu'elles essayent/essaient"

"qu'elles essaient"
```

I want a regular expression that I can use to compare those strings. Is something like this even possible with regular expressions?

Comment: Did you try anything? Are these the only allowed possibilities or can you also have `qu'ils/elles essaient`

Comment: What about `Qu'elles/ils essaient`?

Comment: `qu'ils/elles essaient` is also allowed. Basically either the word before or after the slash, or both words including the slash are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. With regexes, you can have alternate elements like `(il|elle)`, and you can have optional elements like `(s?)`. There are also character sets like `[iy]`.

If your input has the / notation, you'll have to do word-splitting there and translate to the `|` syntax.

Matching the strings that still include / will be just another option:

`(ils|elles|ils/elles)`

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple combinations possible, you might use alternations listing all the options:

```
qu'(?:ils/elles|ils|elles) (?:essayent(?:/essaient)?|essaient)$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `qu'` Match literally
- `(?:ils/elles|ils|elles)`
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `essayent` Match literally
  - `(?:/essaient)?` Optionally match `/essaient`
  - `|` Or
    -`essaient` Match literally
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xuu46E/1)